# What is "Vop" sensitivity unit?

Tags: voltage, datasheet, sensitivity

I am studying the datasheet of an ultrasonic transducer ([Murata MA58MF14](https://www.murata.com/en-gb/products/productdata/8797589405726/MASPWTRE.pdf?1450668610000)). I understand the maximum input voltage unit (voltage peak-to-peak), but **I do not understand what exactly the sensitivity unit "Vop" is?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is volts, measured at Vout of the reference circuit in Figure 2.

That corresponds to the peak voltage relating to the bounce off of the reference object (PVC pole of specified dimensions at 600mm).

The decay time will determine the closest object you can detect, since the transducer is rung up at the resonant frequency during the transmit (8 cycles at 58kHz).

Answer (score 1):

What they are saying is that if you use the circuit shown in figure 2 (that generates pulses and also receives pulses) and you use it in the configuration shown in figure 3 (Test Condition for Overall Sensitivity), you will get an output (op or o/p) of more than 1 volt. That 1 volt is the reflected signal output from the test "wall" in figure 3.